# Split texts with enumerations (lists) with different separators: numbers, hyphens, dots etc into parts

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have texts in which there are enumerations (lists) with different types of separators: numbers, hyphens, dots etc.

For example:

- `"1) it is necessary to place an order, 2) to enter it in the register, 3) to write a conclusion"`, or
- `"1. it is necessary to place an order 2. to enter it in the register 3. to write a conclusion"`, or
- `"- it is necessary to place an order, - to enter it in register, - write a conclusion"`, or
- `"• it is necessary to place an order • enter it in the register • write a conclusion"` and so on.

How should I split these texts into parts, at the separators?

For example, from `"1. it is necessary to place an order 2. to enter it in the register 3. to write a conclusion"` to `[ "1. it is necessary to place an order", "2. to enter it in the register", "3. to write a conclusion"]`.

I wrote this function:

```py
import re

def split_text(text):
    # Define the regular expression patterns for different types of separators
    patterns = [
        r'\d+\)|\d+\.',
        r'-',
        r'•',
    ]

    # Combine the patterns into a single regular expression
    pattern = '|'.join(patterns)

    # Split the text using the regular expression pattern
    parts = re.split(pattern, text)

    # Remove any empty parts
    parts = [part.strip() for part in parts if part.strip()]

    return parts
```

But it doesn't handle this case: `"- it is necessary to place an order office-home - enter it in the register - write a conclusion"`.

I want this input to produce the output `[ "it is necessary to place an order office-home", "to enter it in the register", "to write a conclusion"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to split the text into parts based on different types of separators. Here's an example Python function that accomplishes this:

```
import re

def split_text(text):
    # Define the regular expression patterns for different types of separators
    patterns = [
        r'\d+\)|\d+\.',
        r'(?<!\S)-(?!\S)',
        r'•',
    ]

    # Combine the patterns into a single regular expression
    pattern = '|'.join(patterns)

    # Split the text using the regular expression pattern
    parts = re.split(pattern, text)

    # Remove any empty parts
    parts = [part.strip() for part in parts if part.strip()]

    return parts
```

This function takes a text parameter and splits it into parts based on the defined separators. The regular expression patterns used are as follows:

\d+)|\d+.: Matches numbers followed by ")" or "." (e.g., "1)", "2.", etc.).

(?<!\S)-(?!\S): Matches hyphens that are not preceded or followed by a non-whitespace character. This handles cases where the separator includes the text itself (e.g., "- it is necessary to place an order - enter it in the register").

•: Matches the bullet character "•".

To split the text, we combine all the patterns into a single regular expression using the | (pipe) operator. Then, we use re.split() to split the text based on the pattern. Finally, we remove any empty parts and return the resulting parts.

You can use this function by calling split_text(text) with the text you want to split. For example:

```
text = "1. it is necessary to place an order 2. to enter it in the register 3. to write a conclusion"
result = split_text(text)
print(result)
```

This should output:

```
["1. it is necessary to place an order", "2. to enter it in the register", "3. to write a conclusion"]
```

I hope this will help you! If you have any further questions let me know:)

Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your case `"- it is necessary to place an order office-home - enter it in the register - write a conclusion"` is not handled as you'd like is because of the hyphenation of `office-home`.

This is because your split pattern `r'-'` will cause a break between `office` and `home`. If you want to avoid this, you could specify, for example, to only break if there is a whitespace after the hyphen, ie. `r'-\s'`.

Additionally, if you want to get rid of the leading `-`  from your string, you could include a `\s*` match in your split, giving you the pattern `r'\s*-\s'`.

Taking that altogether gives you the output you'd like:

```py
import re


def split_text(text):
    # Define the regular expression patterns for different types of separators
    patterns = [
        r'\d+\)|\d+\.',
        r'\s*-\s',
        r'•',
    ]

    # Combine the patterns into a single regular expression
    pattern = '|'.join(patterns)

    # Split the text using the regular expression pattern
    parts = re.split(pattern, text)

    # Remove any empty parts
    parts = [part.strip() for part in parts if part.strip()]

    return parts

string = "- it is necessary to place an order office-home - enter it in the register - write a conclusion"

split_text(string)
# ['it is necessary to place an order office-home', 'enter it in the register', 'write a conclusion']
```